# Is there a way to create a table database-side with the result of a query with dbplyr?

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, tidyverse, dbplyr

Suppose I have a connection to a database and a link to a large table created like that:

```
library(tidyverse)
conn <- ROracle::dbConnect(drv, dbname = "IPIAMPR2.WORLD")
patients <- tbl(conn, "patients")
```

I can do the following query:

```
young <- patients %>% filter(age < 18)
```

and then copy the result to the database:

```
copy_to(conn, young, "young")
```

---

#### Question

But is there a way to do something equivalent to the following SQL:

```
create table YOUNG
select *
from PATIENTS
where AGE < 18
```

and have all the work done database-server-side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Use [`compute()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/compute.html).

```r
young <-
  patients %>%
  filter(age < 18) %>%
  compute(name = "young", temporary = FALSE)
```

There is (I believe) no `overwrite = TRUE` option with `compute()`, so precede with `dbExecute(conn, "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS young")` if necessary.

Comment: Ok! `compute` is the verb... I was looking for something similar to `create`